# TypeScript definition file : Exporting an instantiated class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is a specific typescript definition that I cannot currently get working:

```
mapping.ts
class Mapping {
//
}
var mapping = new Mapping();
export = mapping;
```

Which enables the use:

```
import _mapping = require('mapping');
_mapping.doSomething();
```

However I cannot quite get to the solution of how my mapping.d.ts should be structured to show this and cannot get it to compile.

```
mapping.d.ts
export var mapping: Mapping;
```

This fails since the usage would now be:

```
 _mapping.mapping.doSomething();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated besides updating the usage to include the object name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax `export =` in the definitions file:

```
// mapping.d.ts
let mapping: Mapping;
export = mapping;
```